# Spring. One-time add session attributes after authorization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

Stack: Spring Security and Thymeleaf.

I have the following problem: I want to show or not show some elements in all html templates depending on user's role.

So, I need a boolean variable "isAdmin" in all templates so that I can use it in conditions:

```
<p th:if="${isAdmin}">Admin functionality</p>
```

Please help me find the best solution. What I tried:

**Option 1.**
I can add variable to the model in all controllers. But I think it's a bad practice.

**Option 2.**
I can inject variable into the body with "th:with" directly from the session:

```
<body th:with="isAdmin=
    ${session
    .SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
    .getAuthentication()
    .getAuthorities()
    .contains(T(com.example.model.enums.Role).ADMIN)}">
```

But it's too long declaration.
I also didn't fin information about the scope of global variables in Thymeleaf.

**Option 3.**
I understood I should add custom attribute in user session. And I should add it only one-time after authorization. I couldn't think of something better than overriding successForwardUrl, adding attribute in new controller and redirecting to the main page.

```
.formLogin()
.loginPage("/login").permitAll()
.successForwardUrl("/login/setAttributes")
```

```
@PostMapping ("login/setAttributes")
public String postLoginPage(HttpSession httpSession) {
    boolean isAdmin = SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext()
            .getAuthentication()
            .getAuthorities()
            .contains(Role.ADMIN);

    httpSession.setAttribute("isAdmin", isAdmin);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

But I still think it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the best solution

Thymeleaf has its special integration with Spring Security

You can check [docs here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html)

First of all, you should add `org.thymeleaf.extras` dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Next step. Add Thymeleaf `sec` namespace to your `.html` template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

Finally, you can check user role and show specific content for different role:

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <p>Admin functionality</p>
</div>
```

Also `sec:authentication` can be used to retrieve user name and roles:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    User: <span sec:authentication="name">User name</span>
    Roles: <span sec:authentication="principal.authorities">User roles</span>
</div>
```